# ESlint local plugin prevents npm to install deps on CI

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint, eslintrc

I have created a custom ESLint plugin without publishing it, as I really need it for that project only.
I just created it in a folder inside my project as I only want to use it internally, nor I think I need to create a new repo for it.
Issue is that it prevents `npm ci` or `npm i` to properly install deps on CI, while I have no problems locally.

Here is the error I get from CI

```
$ npm ci && npm run build:mfe
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /builds/teleoptometry/telo-ui/node_modules/eslint-plugin-telo/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/builds/teleoptometry/telo-ui/node_modules/eslint-plugin-telo/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-14T10_31_53_477Z-debug.log
```

Here is what I have.

```js
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  extends: ['react-app'],
  plugins: ['react-hooks', 'telo'], <--- telo is my plugin name
  rules: {
    [...other rules...]
    'telo/use-telo-navigate': 'error', <--- my ryle
  },
}
```

```json
// package.json

"devDependencies": {
  "eslint-plugin-telo": "file:./eslint"
}
```

My eslint folder is as follows

[image]

```js
// my ./src/eslint/index.js file just imports the rule

module.exports = {
  rules: { 'use-telo-navigate': require('./rules/use-telo-navigate') },
}
```

I think the issue is in the way I link the eslint plugin in `package.json`, but I cannot understand why it works on my machine.

I guess I should try to extract eslint plugin in a new repo (unfortunaly I am not using a monorepo) and import it with `npm link` or something, but I would like to avoid it.

I would expect my setup to be working as is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
ESLint does not allow anymore to plug rules at runtime from a dir or file as it was with `--rulesDir` argument. It **must** be a package. See [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2715).

So my fix was to just run `cd ./eslint && npm init -y`, that is to create a `package.json` file alongside the `index.js` file

BTW, there are plugins to allow old `--rulesDir` behavior, see for example [eslint-plugin-local-rules](https://github.com/cletusw/eslint-plugin-local-rules) and [eslint-plugin-rulesdir](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/eslint-plugin-rulesdir)